# apache POI opening docx file failure

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I tried to get Doc/Docx Text  content . it seems that apache POI do that . i included the dependencies in pom.xml . I tried many code samples like  this :

```
    File docFile1=new File("c:\\document1.docx")
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(docFile1);
    XWPFDocument docIn = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
    XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docIn);
    String docText = extractor.getText();
```

this line of code does not compile . eclipse error is in line 3  (The constructor XWPFDocument(FileInputStream) is undefined ) . Many Web ressources that this should work .but it didn't . any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue . including the last POI version resolve the probleme.at the time of the writing it's 3.7 .

Comment: Please verify this. On [poi webpage](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) it states *The latest stable release is Apache POI 3.8*. 3.8 is the version I use and the archive is dated 20120326.